# Android : Unable to instantiate application

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I have an app where I have implement dagger and when lunch my app I am getting this error :-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.heet.sleepmagic, PID: 18977
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.heet.sleepmagic.MainApp package com.heet.sleepmagic: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.heet.sleepmagic.MainApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~vhnGOdaJiLk6ztERW8DzSg==/com.heet.sleepmagic-8TvtgzEu5imBuAIS-WXaGQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~vhnGOdaJiLk6ztERW8DzSg==/com.heet.sleepmagic-8TvtgzEu5imBuAIS-WXaGQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1466)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6720)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.heet.sleepmagic.MainApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~vhnGOdaJiLk6ztERW8DzSg==/com.heet.sleepmagic-8TvtgzEu5imBuAIS-WXaGQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~vhnGOdaJiLk6ztERW8DzSg==/com.heet.sleepmagic-8TvtgzEu5imBuAIS-WXaGQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1243)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1458)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6720) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/heet/sleepmagic/Hilt_MainApp;
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.heet.sleepmagic.Hilt_MainApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~vhnGOdaJiLk6ztERW8DzSg==/com.heet.sleepmagic-8TvtgzEu5imBuAIS-WXaGQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~vhnGOdaJiLk6ztERW8DzSg==/com.heet.sleepmagic-8TvtgzEu5imBuAIS-WXaGQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 19 more
```

and my **build.gradle** is like this :-

```
 plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id ("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.heet.sleepmagic"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.heet.sleepmagic"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    // Compose dependencies
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2")
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.4")

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42")
    annotationProcessor ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.42")
    annotationProcessor ("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")

    //Coil
    implementation ("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.3.0")
}
```

and my **manifest** is like this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name=".MainApp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SleepMagic"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SleepMagic">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My **application** class :-

```
package com.heet.sleepmagic

import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp 
class MainApp:Application()
```

My **MainActivity** :-

```
package com.heet.sleepmagic

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.heet.sleepmagic.ui.navigation.Navigation
import com.heet.sleepmagic.ui.theme.HattonFontFamily
import com.heet.sleepmagic.ui.theme.HattonTypography
import com.heet.sleepmagic.ui.theme.SleepMagicTheme
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SleepMagicTheme {
                Navigation(navController = rememberNavController())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this error is giving me after I updated my android studio to **Giraffe | 2022.3.1** and I think it is because of any dagger's class problem or something. Help me out this would be very appreciatable. Thank you.

I really appreciate your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Your logcat is blank, can't figure out anything

Comment: @DanishAnsari swipe right to see that I dont know how to fix that

Comment: Did you try Invalidate Cache?

Comment: @amtrax No, how to do that?

Comment: @heetkanabar To clear cache, from the main menu in Android Studio , select File | Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Comment: @heetkanabar instead of `annotationProcessor` try to use `kapt`. Check official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#setup

Comment: @DanishAnsari hi, I just posted my solution and you were right I did not do right implementation in gradle. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution and it was because of my wrong implementation of my gradle files I did not know how to add dependencies in kotlin so I learned it and did some changes like this and it solved my problem :-

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

//Dagger - Hilt
    kapt ("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
```

my build.gradle (app module):-

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}
```

And Also I got an other error where I have to change my jvm version from 1.8  to jvm 17 :-

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
```